# Nginx - if pattern 404 - go to

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have list of urls like:

```
domain.com/some-url-key-with-possible-id-after-it-99999.html
```

I need to try that URL, and IF it returns 404, redirect to:

```
domain.com/some-url-key-with-possible-id-after-it.html
```

Is that possible?

```
location ~ /([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+).html$ {
## IF ABOVE IS 404
    return       301 http://domain.com/$1.html;
## ENDIF
}
```

I found something like this:

```
server {
        listen             12440;
        root       /some/path/here/nginx/html/noahc/;
        server_name    www.domain.net, domain.net;
        port_in_redirect off;

        location /{
            error_page 404 =  @foobar;
        }

        location @foobar {
            rewrite  .*  / permanent;
        }    
 }
```

But it doesn't satisfy me, because I need to redirect to url with variable from request pattern. It could be ok, if I'll be able to pass ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+) to it as an argument.

Comment: why do you want to use a variable for url? what ar you requesting with the variable ?

Comment: The result of: ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+)

Comment: this are pattern, but what do you want to do with them ?

Comment: look here http://serverfault.com/a/569683

Comment: do you mean missing file or a cgi-subrequest.

Comment: @Blueblazer172 
redirect to:     return       301 http://domain.com/$1.html;
where variable $1 is the result of pattern match ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+).

Answer (score 0):

So you have a URI and you would like to rewrite it if the static file does not exist. Use `try_files` to test for file existence.

```
root /path/to/docroot;

location ~ ^(/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-[0-9]+\.html$ {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    return 301 $1.html;
}
```

You can use `return 301` or `rewrite ... last` in the named location, depending on how visible you want the rewrite to be.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html) for help with `nginx` directives.

Comment: is it that simple? Let me check! :)

Comment: It's not working as intended - It redirects every time, not only if request is 404.

Comment: You mean `try_files $uri` cannot find your file? Have you set `root` correctly, and have you looked at your logfiles?